# Is there a non-measure-theoretic foundation of probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, foundations

The mathematical foundations of modern probability theory are based on the works of Kolmogorov who formalized the notion of a probability measure. In my experience this framework has at-worst been counter intuitive, and often quite fruitful to understand, but I have wondered if there are alternative foundations for probability.

Is there a mathematically rigorous alternative to measure theory as a foundation for probability theory?

Comment: von Mises had another approach that you can find in many [places](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-12/issue-2/On-the-Foundations-of-Probability-and-Statistics/10.1214/aoms/1177731748.full) I would not think is more intuitive. In any event, what (in your experience) have agains the frame work of Kolmogorov. Other approaches that I have seen are based on work of [de Finetti](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20012240).

Comment: There is also a formalization by Cox that does not allow for countable additivity of events: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%27s_theorem